# Como codificar una URL (urlencode) en un script de bash?

Tags: bash, urlencoding

Estoy generando un script que solicita datos de un usuario,
luego estos datos se deben enviar en formato de URL (url-encoded) a otro script.

```
echo -n "Search: "
read SEARCH
URLENCODED_VALUE=???
./searchcommand $URLENCODED_VALUE
```

Existe un comando estandar que pueda realizar esto?

He probado el siguiente codigo:

```
URLENCODED_VALUE=$(echo "$SEARCH" | sed -e 's/%/%25/g' -e 's/ /%20/g' -e 's/!/%21/g' -e 's/"/%22/g' -e 's/#/%23/g' -e 's/\$/%24/g' -e 's/\&/%26/g' -e 's/'\''/%27/g' -e 's/(/%28/g' -e 's/)/%29/g' -e 's/\*/%2a/g' -e 's/+/%2b/g' -e 's/,/%2c/g' -e 's/-/%2d/g' -e 's/\./%2e/g' -e 's/\//%2f/g' -e 's/:/%3a/g' -e 's/;/%3b/g' -e 's//%3e/g' -e 's/?/%3f/g' -e 's/@/%40/g' -e 's/\[/%5b/g' -e 's/\\/%5c/g' -e 's/\]/%5d/g' -e 's/\^/%5e/g' -e 's/_/%5f/g' -e 's/`/%60/g' -e 's/{/%7b/g' -e 's/|/%7c/g' -e 's/}/%7d/g' -e 's/~/%7e/g')
```

Funciona, pero creo que debe haber algo mas sencillo, que sea mas general (pueden haber casos no cubiertos) y que no requieraun codigo tan largo o librerias/imports adicionales.

La idea es entregar un valor como `K7@e49:b234` y obtener `K7%40e49%3Ab234`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser usando Perl

```
...

URLENCODED_VALUE="$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "$SEARCH")"
...
```

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo, entrega el valor según lo que necesito para este caso.

Answer (score 1):

Esta sucesion de comandos tambien genera un valor correcto, todos son comandos estandar.

```
URLENCODED_VALUE=$(echo -e "$SEARCH" | od -An -tx1 | tr ' ' % | xargs printf "%s")
```

La salida es una codificacion URL valida, con el detalle de que codifica cada caracter incluso los que no requieren codificar.

`K7@e49:b234` ==>  `%4b%37%40%65%34%39%3a%62%32%33%34%0a`